# MySQL equivalent of SQLite SQLiteConnectionContext

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, sqlite

I'm wondering what the MySQL eqivalent of the SQLiteConnectionContext class is. I need this to be able to have a common connection context for my program. I'm creating an entity based solution that will push and pull data from a MySQL database. If there is a better way to do this I'm open to that as well. Below is the SQLite version of what I am looking for.

```
/// <summary>
/// A ConnectionContext common for all of the Inventory project
/// </summary>
public class InventoryConnectionContext : SQLiteConnectionContext
{
    public InventoryConnectionContext(bool connect = true)
        : base(InventoryConnectionString, connect)
    {
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Constructs a BudgetConnectionContext and optionally opens the connection
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="connectString">Connection string that points to a connection aside from the default connection</param>
    /// <param name="connect">Specifies whether or not to open the connection</param>
    public InventoryConnectionContext(string connectString, bool connect = true)
        : base(connectString)
    {
        if (connect)
            Connect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are dynamically generated under the .edmx file in the entities project you put them in. It seems to follow this format *(nameofdb)*Entities and is an instantiable class.

To get this to generate you need to drop the EntityFrameWork, MySQL.Data, MySQL.Data.Entities NuGets and then pull your server in. You do this by clicking View->Server Explorer then right click on SharePoint Connections (may be named slightly differently) and add your server that way. You can then import all of your tables and Entities. They will show up under the .tt file and are also autogenerated instantiable classes. All of these can be worked with together by knowing that you need a context and an entity to modify a db. [context].[table].Add/Delete; An example `context.test_table.Add(myEntity);`.

;tldr : Add the server, it shows up under the .edmx file as a .context.tt with the classes under that.